# Different parameterizations of a curve on the torus.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $T=\{[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4] | x_1^2+x_2^2=1,x_3^2+x_4^2=1\}$

The map $r:[0,2\pi]^2 \rightarrow T$ given by

$ e(t)=[\cos(at),\sin(at),\cos(bt),\sin(bt)] $ be a parameterization of a curve on the set $T$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

What is the significance of the ratio $\frac{a}{b}$? What difference does it make rather $\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$? My gut is telling me it has something to do with whether the map is onto or not. Like if $\frac{a}{b} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ then perhaps the map will be onto for some reason, but I don't know how to go about exploring this idea, much less make it rigorous.

Comment: $e(t)$ is a function $\mathbb{R} \to T$, it is $L$ periodic iff $aL \in 2\pi \mathbb{Z}, bL \in 2\pi \mathbb{Z}$, if so it means $aL = 2\pi n, bL = 2\pi m$ so $a/b = n/m\in \mathbb{Q}$. The image of $e$ is never surjective (it is a curve in a surface), but iff $a/b \not \in \mathbb{Q}$ then it is injective and dense.

Comment: I was thinking it might be subjective because, although I have not studied them, I know that space filling curves exist.

Comment: Right in general I should add some restrictions (like uniformly smooth $\mathbb{R} \to T$) to conclude it is not onto, but here it is kind of obvious because if $e$ passes through every point then it also passes two times at the same point so it is periodic which is a contradiction